# classpath element not a jar warning in ant junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, ant, junit4

My project has several types of elements like xml, json, java, jar files. They are present in src folder under several subfolders. I have included all of them in my ant build xml. 
The build file is succesfully compiled.
After compilation, "Test:" is shown on console for junit.
Then several warnings are shown as below:

CLASSPATH element C:\buildscripts\junitAntreal\src\unittest\resources\log4j.properties is not a JAR.

CLASSPATH element C:\buildscripts\junitAntreal\src\unittest\resources\spring\appServlet\controllers.xml is not a JAR.

These warnings are several and present for all files including java files. These warnings go on repeating again and again for an hour and then junit results are shown.

Are these "classpath elements" warning important, if so how can i resolve them? Else How can i skip these warnings and directly get my junit results? Thank you.

Below is my build xml:

```
<project name = "JunitTest" default = "test" basedir = ".">
    <record name="C:\apache-ant-1.10.1\logfile.txt" action="start" append="false" />
   <property name = "testdir" location = "test" />
   <property name = "srcdir" location = "src" />
   <property name = "full-compile" value = "true" />

   <path id = "classpath.base"/>

   <path id = "classpath.test">
      <pathelement location = "lib/junit-4.12.jar" />
      <pathelement location = "lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" />
      <pathelement location = "${testdir}" />
      <pathelement location = "${srcdir}" />
      <pathelement location="src/WEB-INF/classes"/>
      <fileset dir="src">
        <include name="**/*.java" />
        <include name="**/*.json" />
        <include name="**/*.xml" />
        <include name="**/*.properties" />
        <include name="**/*.jsp" />
        <include name="**/*.css" />
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
        <include name="**/*.js" />
        <include name="**/*.MF" />
        <include name="**/*.xliff" />
        <include name="**/*.sql" />
        <include name="**/*.xsl" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
      <path refid = "classpath.base" />
   </path>

   <target name = "clean" >
      <delete verbose = "${full-compile}">
         <fileset dir = "${testdir}" includes = "**/*.class" />
      </delete>
   </target>

   <target name = "compile" depends = "clean">
      <javac srcdir = "${srcdir}" destdir = "${testdir}" 
         verbose = "${full-compile}">
         <classpath refid = "classpath.test"/>
      </javac>
   </target>

   <target name = "test" depends = "compile">
      <junit>
         <classpath refid = "classpath.test" />
         <formatter type = "brief" usefile = "false" />
         <test name = "TestMeFile" />
      </junit>
   </target>

    <record name="C:\apache-ant-1.10.1\logfile.txt" action="stop"/>
</project>
```

Comment: Try not adding things that aren't jars to the classpath that you're passing to junit.

Comment: Also, note that your `record` task is not going to work as you probably expect. It will start and stop before any targets are run.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Removing <classpath refid = "classpath.test" /> in junit did it.